# Commerce View + Multiple products on product_reference field

Tags: commerce

i'm having troubles at making a custom view of some products i have in my commerce.

Here is a simple example:
I have 1 T-shirt, with 4 colors. Each color has it's own price (they are all different), and it's own images (4 images per t-shirt).

[Now, i need something like this](http://www.freepeople.com/catalog-apr-12-catalog-apr-12-catalog-items/embellished-palms-tunic/)

[And my real design is this one](http://faareia.com.ar/productos.jpg)

I just seen, that Views can't be used since there is now way to replicate the default node functionality, since every field won't refresh (remember there are 4 variables...prices and images)

I can use a "custom node-type.tpl.php", and make some custom "field-field-name.tpl.php" too, to make my design.......BUT how do i add an image gallery per product???

hope it's clear, i do not speak english.
thanks for everthing.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone need an image gallery for commerce, and you have a node referencing multiple product which have multiple images, [Image zoom](http://drupal.org/project/imagezoom) is the correct module.